# Convert model to list before passing it to view

Tags: c#, list

I got this model in my project:

```
public class ListOfProducts
    {
        public List<string> ProductNames { get; set; }       
        public List<string> ProductUrls { get; set; }

    }
```

The way I pass it to my view is:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var listOfUrls = GetListOfHrefs();    //Methods for giving values
            var listOfProductNames = GetListOfProductNames();//Methods for giving values
            var model = new ListOfProducts {ProductUrls = listOfUrls, ProductNames = listOfProductNames, ProductGtin = listofGti};


            return View(model);
        }
```

I would like to pass my model to the view as a list in order to loop through it the way i Want...Can I convert my model to a list before passing it?

Tried `model.Tolist(`) but the intellisense could no find the `Tolist-Part`

EDIT:

I really need to acess both properties in the same context..In this case the `Artice`

```
 <article id="post-62" class="post-62 x-portfolio type-x-portfolio status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry has-post-thumbnail x-portfolio-5e9a5c5e0b6c2e1342bfccc9cacb084f x-portfolio-3ce959340d6fed7ed4f041884b46387c">

                <div class="entry-wrap cf">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h2 class="entry-title entry-title-portfolio">
                           <p>@product</p>
                        </h2>
                    </header>
                </div>
                <p>@url</p>
                <span class="visually-hidden"><span class="author vcard"><span class="fn">addiadmin</span></span><span class="entry-title">Gluten &#038; Mjölkfri Raggmunk</span><time class="entry-date updated" datetime="2014-05-21T08:23:32+00:00">05.21.2014</time></span>



            </article>
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the ProductUrls and the ProductNames?

Comment: Which list would you want to pass to your View class?

Comment: I would like to convert the class ListOfProducts to a list. Wait 1mmin and i´ll show my view.

Comment: Does each entry in the ProductNames match one entry in ProductUrls?

Comment: Yes Rob, they match. Please se edit for the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListOfProducts` is an object with properties that are lists.

I think what you are wanting is

```
@model ListOfProducts

foreach (var item in Model.ProductNames)
{
  ....

foreach (var item in Model.ProductUrls )
{
  ....
```

**EDIT**: Following on from your comments, you could do this (but see comments at end)

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductNames.Count; i++)
{
  <article id="post-62"...
    <div class="entry-...
      <header class="entry...
        <h2 class="entry-title...
          <p>Model.ProductNames[i]</p>
        </h2>
      </header>  
    </div>
    <p>Model.ProductUrls[i]</p>
    ....
  </article>
}
```

but this will only work if both `ProductNames` and `ProductUrls` contain exactly the same number of elements, in which case perhaps you should re-think your model

```
public class Product
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Url {get; set;}
}
```

Then create a `List<Product>` in you `Index' action method and pass that to the view

Comment: You were absolutley right! This is what i wanted.
Sorry everybody for being unclear with what I wanted, hopefullt this can help someone else!

Comment: Are you creating html elements based on `ProductNames` and `ProductUrls`? If so it may be better to use a `for (int i = 0; ...)` loop so that you create the correct names for post back. See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841504/how-do-i-model-bind-a-list-of-listselectitem-using-mvc-net/23842106#23842106)

Comment: Do you mean that it is possible for me to "combine" the two loops in your answe above into 1 for-loop? That would help alot because i would really like to displat the two properties in the same "article"..

Comment: I was referring to creating inputs for post back (I was not sure if this was a form for post back or not) but if you know that both lists are exactly the same length then use can use a single loop `for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductNames.Count; i++) {...` and do something with `Model.ProductNames[i]` and `Model.ProductUrls[i]`

Comment: If you have the time, please have a look at my edit, I try to acess both properties in the same Article, Is it maybe possible to acess both properties in the sam loop?

Answer (score 3):

its the same to ask "I wanna send MyClass as list ...", this is a basic OOB(Object-oriented programming) concept question IMO..so send List{MyClass} , you are sending one object name ListOfProducts which contains 2 lists, do  you mean List{ListOfProducts} ? you can attach any Model , any parameters to the View as you want to them , **modify it(any Model /ViewBag.Something) to your needs as you please** , you are the game ruler

```
 return View(new List<ListOfProducts >{model});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently convert `ListOfProducts` to a list as it's has nothing to do with a list. It's a new type which you have defined in your code.

if you want it to be a list, you should inherit from `IEnumerable` for example or ICollection and implement the required functions.

Actually, to implement `IEnumerable`,  you need a property in `ListOfProducts` that will contain all your `List<String>` so you could iterate on that !

Answer (score 1):

If I assume that each entry in the list ProductNames matches one entry in ProductUrls, then what your really after is a list of Products and the design is missing the 'Product' class.

Create a class like:

```
public class Product
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Url {get; set;}
}
```

Now replace your 'ListOfProducts' with:

```
List<Product>()
```

Now you have a list of products. Your class ListOfProducts is not required.